# Can't change the value of href with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, href

This is the code:

JS:

```
function f1(){
    document.getElementById('test').href="link2";
};
```

HTML:

```
<a href='link1' id='test' onclick='f1();'> Text </a>
```

The debugger says f1() is not defined. What could it be? The "a" tag is inside a "span" tag, maybe that?

Edit: Sorry for the JQuery thingy I added it to see what happened :P

I forgot to put the linking of the JS file, my bad:

```
<script type='script' href='javascript.js'> </script>
```

Comment: I normally get that error from the debugger when there's a syntax mistake somewhere in my javascript code.  Is there anything else in the same file?

Comment: Where is `f1()` is defined?

Answer (score 2):

Where did you put `f1`? `onclick` find the function in the global scope, if you didn't define the function in global, then it will not be found.

And `$(document).getElementById('test').href="link2";` is wrong too,

it should just be `document.getElementById('test').href="link2";`

Also, if you are using jQuery, then the best way not use the inline `onclick`:

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').click(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', 'link2');
    });
});
```