# How to change the value of <a> tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here my html code

```
<a href="myfile.html" id='tagId'>Old File</>
```

I want to change the value of  tag with name "New File"

So i wrote javascript like document.getElementById("tagId").value='New File';

I thought output like `<a href="myfile.html" id='tagId'>New File</a>`

But it's not working .can anyone help ?

Comment: Use `innerHTML` instead of `value`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582803/cant-change-the-value-of-href-with-javascript

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `.innerHTML` or `.innerText`

```
document.getElementById("tagId").innerHTML="new File",
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("tagId").innerText="new File",
```

OR
Note: Not all browsers support `innerTEXT`, so use `textContent` if you want to change the text only,

Reference [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428965/mozilla-firefox-not-getting-value-innertext#answer-10429006)

So like @Amith Joki said, use like

```
 document.getElementById("tagId").textContent="new File",
```

Since `<a>` tag doesn't have value property, you need change the html of anchor tags.

Using Jquery

```
$("#tagId").html("new File");
```

OR

```
$("#tagId").text("new File");
```

**Edit**

If you want to change the href using javascript, USe like this

```
 document.getElementById("tagId").href="new href";
```

USing jquery,

```
$("#tagid").attr("href","new value");
```

Comment: I will give you the benefit of the doubt (comment removed). I was watching your edits... (they each appeared after identical ones were posted).

Comment: Although as you just added `textContent` out of nowhere, which was in yet another answer, I am starting to have doubts again :)

Comment: Sure sure, just don't forget to provide compatibility references (or credit to other authors, if you do happen get ideas from there, which is fine too) :)

Comment: Hi Anoop,like the same way how to get href value and how to change it ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.html()` to get/set html:

```
 $('#tagId').html('New File')
```

OR

```
 $("#tagId").text("new File");
```

Comment: +1: for giving jQuery answer first (which was soon copied!) :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `.textContent` properties to set the text of `<a>`.

```
document.getElementById("tagId").textContent ="new File"
```

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie ah! Those upvotes don't count now. I've reached 200 limit already :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54727/discussion-between-amit-joki-and-trueblueaussie).

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$("#tagid").text("New File");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple code

```
<script>
    $("tagId").html("new File");

</script>
```