# Change the css on a href

Tags: javascript, css, href

How can i change the css of my menu link, using javascript?

```
<li>
<a href="here is the link">
Промоции </a>
</li>
```

Because i cant add id on `<li>` or `<a>` ! Im using opencart, and im just trying to modify a theme

Comment: a [href="https://zachoveka.com/promo"] { @content }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934978/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-tag-using-javascript

Comment: add a class and style it? What is your actual issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246273/how-to-change-the-display-of-a-div-using-javascript

Comment: do with [`classList.add`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiVit7uwpjXAhXMrI8KHS18AM0QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FElement%2FclassList&usg=AOvVaw2KqNy6HmXczlfIXmNUIwiH) or [`document.element.style.cssproperties`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_4qmCw5jXAhWJs48KHXRhDCsQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FHTMLElement%2Fstyle&usg=AOvVaw3ETHKxAbgJzqDztFYqxu9Z)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241915/how-to-change-css-property-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

For all menu links,

```
// CSS Code
.custom_style { color: red; }

// JS Code
const links = document.querySelectorAll('li a');

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].classList.add('custom_style');
}
```

For single menu link,

```
// CSS Code
.custom_style { color: red; }

// JS Code
const link = document.querySelector('li a');
link.classList.add('custom_style');
```

Comment: if i put this code, it will put `custom_style` on every element,i want to put it on one exact link!